# Flexbox & Edge: Flex direction not working when printing

Tags: html, css, printing, flexbox, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to modify the layout of a page for print. I have content in a sidebar that is supposed to be shown before the article when printed. Which in this example below works fine in Chrome.

[image: how it's supposed to work]

But for some reason, in Edge (big surprise...), it doesn't add the content to the beginning of page 1, but instead adds it randomly to the beginning of page 3. Right in the middle of another section. Not sure why this is.

[image: displayed in Edge]

This content is located here:
https://www.bipc.com/california-privacy-bill-big-implications-for-us-businesses-part-i

The CSS I used for this section is below. **.layout-sidebar** just refers to a content area that includes a sidebar and **.row** refers to the container which includes the 2 children *.col-content* and *.col-sidebar*

```
@media print {
 .layout-sidebar .row {
    display: flex !important;
    flex-direction: column-reverse !important;
  }
}
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. If there is additional information needed, please let me know.

Thank you in advance.